# Global Variable using while

Tags: python, global-variables

I am trying to increment a global variable in my code but when I use the key word global it says n has already been used. I am trying to increment n so I can assign each person 1 through 27 to a team.
Thank in advance

```
 my_team =  27 % 4
 team_1 = ""
 team_2 = ""
 team_3 = ""
 team_4 = ""
 team_5 = ""
 team_6 = ""
 team_7 = ""
 print(my_team)
 global n
 n = 1
 for n in range(1, 28):


while n <= 4  :
    global n
    team_1 = team_1 + str(n) + " "
    n = n + 1
    if n == 5:
        break

for n in range (4,8):
    n= n + 1
    team_2 = team_2 + str(n)



while n < 13 and n > 8:

    team_3 =team_3 + str(n)
    n= n + 1


while n < 17 and n > 12:

    team_4 = team_4 + str(n)
    n= n + 1


while n < 21 and n > 16:

    team_5 = team_5 + str(n)
    n= n + 1


while n < 25 and n > 20:

    team_6 = team_6 +str(n)
    n= n + 1

while n < 28 and n > 24:

    team_7 = team_7 + str(n)
    n = n+1


print(team_1)
```

Comment: A couple of things:
1) Your formatting is off so I can't tell where the indents should be
2) Instead of 'team_x = team_x + str(n)' 'team_x += str(n)' will work too
3) If this code ran perfectly what would the result(s) be?

Comment: This makes no sense, your entire code is in the global scope, so a `global` statement *doesn't do anything* and wouldn't be needed here. In general, you should avoid global mutable state, but that's another issue

Answer (score 0):

```py
my_team = 27 % 4
team_1 = ""
team_2 = ""
team_3 = ""
team_4 = ""
team_5 = ""
team_6 = ""
team_7 = ""
print(my_team)
n = 1

while n <= 4:
    team_1 += str(n) + " "
    n += 1

while 4 < n <= 8:
    team_2 += str(n) + " "
    n += 1

while 8 < n <= 12:
    team_3 += str(n) + " "
    n += 1

while 12 < n <= 16:
    team_4 += str(n) + " "
    n += 1

while 16 < n <= 21:
    team_5 += str(n) + " "
    n += 1

while 21 < n <= 25:
    team_6 += str(n) + " "
    n += 1

while 25 < n <= 28:
    team_7 += str(n) + " "
    n += 1

print(team_1)
print(team_2)
print(team_3)
print(team_4)
print(team_5)
print(team_6)
print(team_7)
```

I've fixed some other problems according to what I think is your goal and made a few other changes which you might be able to learn from.